# Stuffing in the middle

Tags: wordplay, pattern

What peculiar property do all these words have in common?

```
BE

CONTENT

CRED

DO

EVENS

FIRS

HE

INNS

MUSS

RATS

RED

SHILLS

SLED

SLY

SPRY

STAGS

STRAY

STY

TAPS

WED
```

---

**Afterword:**

> I would have liked to have included RAIN and RATE because they're so much fun, but I anticipated someone would contest them on a technicality:  the –ING– gets put at the beginning, not stuffed in the middle.
>
>   Here are some others that didn't make the shortlist:  BED, DOES, FRY, MATS, SWARM.
>
>   There is also an entire family of words like SING ––> SINGING in which there could be ambiguity as to whether the additional –ING– has been put at the end or stuffed in the middle.
>   BINGING, BRINGING, CLINGING, CRINGING, DINGING, FLINGING, FRINGING, HAMSTRINGING, HANDWRINGING, HINGING, IMPINGING, INFRINGING, MUDSLINGING, PINGING, RINGING, SINGING, SLINGING, SPRINGING, STINGING, STRINGING, SWINGING, UNHINGING, UPBRINGING, UPBRINGINGS, WINGING, WRINGING, ZINGING

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They all

> can have ING inserted internally to make a new word. Binge, contingent, cringed, dingo, evenings, ..., winged.

The title

> is of course missing a space. "Stuff ING in the middle."

Comment: 2 in a row!!! (+1 x 2)